# resultado de função é dado como undefined em javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

tenho o seguinte código :

```
function calculaDiasDeVida(idade) {
    var dias = idade * 365;
};
function calculaBatimentos(dias){
    var batimentos = dias * 24 * 60 * 80;
};
idade = parseInt(prompt(nome + ", agora, quantos anos você tem ?"));
var dias = calculaDiasDeVida(idade);
var batimentos = calculaBatimentos(dias);
document.write("<br> Você já viveu " + dias + " dias ao longo de sua vida, e seu coração bateu cerca de " + batimentos + " vezes");
```

No caso, ao realizar a conta, os valores 'dias' e 'batimentos' são dados como `undefined`, gostaría de saber, como corrigir o erro, e o porque de ele estar ocorrendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está retornando o resultado. Para fazer isso você precisa de um `return`:

```
function calculaDiasDeVida(idade) {
    return idade * 365;
};

function calculaBatimentos(dias){
    return dias * 24 * 60 * 80;
};
```

Seu exemplo, substituindo as funções, ficaria similar a:

```js
var nome = "Murilo";

function calculaDiasDeVida(idade) {
    return idade * 365;
};
function calculaBatimentos(dias){
    return dias * 24 * 60 * 80;
};
idade = parseInt(prompt(nome + ", agora, quantos anos você tem ?"));
var dias = calculaDiasDeVida(idade);
var batimentos = calculaBatimentos(dias);
document.write("Você já viveu " + dias + " dias ao longo de sua vida, e seu coração bateu cerca de " + batimentos + " vezes");
```

Comment: então dou um return em dias e batimentos ?

Comment: @MuriloGambôa sim, substitua as funções como exemplo acima